# Record screen, audio and webcam in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to record my screen, audio and webcam in Ubuntu. Any suggestion for good software to do this?

Comment: They are 7 years old posts.

Comment: Doesn't mean they wouldn't work.

Comment: @edwinksl - Correct! I just tried couple of them like VokoScreen, they worked fine for me on 17.10.